# Is there a better way to achieve this? '000000'.slice(0, -'434'.length) + '434' = '000434'

Tags: javascript

Yep, the title says pretty much everything. Basically I want a default X-digit number which is all zeros. Then, from this number, I want to replace the last characters with other numbers. For example, if I have '434', and the default is '000000', the result should be '000434'.

In Ruby, this is the equivalent of doing `'%.6d' % 434` and it returns `'000434'`. If the number I want to save has more than 6 digits, I just use that number instead. I realized that as I'm working with strings I could use this solution:

```js
let base = '000000'
let str = '434'
console.log(base.slice(0, -str.length) + str)
```

Buuut, even if it's a simple approach, I don't know if it's the best. What daya' think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For compatibility with older JS environments, you can depend only on a simpler slice:

```
(base + str).slice(-6)
```

For modern ones, `padStart` is available:

```
str.padStart(6, '0')   // or String(num)
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has [`string.padStart(length, padString)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

```js
let str = '434'
const updated = str.padStart(6, '0')
console.log(updated)
```